# Why is the margin of my img clickable?

Tags: css

Why is the margin of my image clickable? The strange thing is when I change the height and width to 100px the margin disappears.  (on Firefox)

My CSS for the img is

```
#cheese {
    margin-right: 100px;
}
```

Here is jsfiddle link: 
http://jsfiddle.net/6e4gM/3/

Thanks!

Comment: I can't repro this in Chrome.

Comment: The problem is on Firefox.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because the margin is on `<img>` which is inside `<a>`. Everything inside `<a>` is clickable, including margin's of children.

Webkit browsers (Chrome, Safari) have a bit of funny behavior in this, they only seem to apply clickability on the margin when that element is styled with a background or borders or something:

http://jsfiddle.net/6e4gM/12/

IE (I tested 11) is even worse, it ignores the margins in all cases.

You can get universal behavior if you add `display: inline-block;` to the `<a>` elements:

http://jsfiddle.net/6e4gM/14/

Comment: Is there a way to make the margins not clickable?

Comment: @hktir what did you think of putting the margin om the `<a>`?